# Manage and accumulate subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a function that produces triangles and quadrilaterals (called 'trisq') in red or green, resp. My goal is to make an arrangement of these shapes on the same plot by running a loop over my drawing function.

I can draw multiple shapes and call plt.show() on it which works fine but after that I won't be able to add more shapes as it gives me a blank output.

I think my issue is that I don't know how to control subplot command. Please see my inline comment in the code for how it goes wrong. What would be the cleanest way to do this? Thanks!

(Btw, this is my first time posting here. I think my question is basic but I hope that at least I've posed it in a clear way).

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def trisq(points):
    inf = 20
    plt.xlim(-inf, inf)
    plt.ylim(-inf, inf)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

    ver = np.array(points)

    polygon = Polygon(ver, True)
    patches = []
    patches.append(polygon)
    if len(points) == 3:
        color = 'red'
    elif len(points) == 4:
        color = 'green'
    p = PatchCollection(patches, color = color,cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)

    ax.add_collection(p)

trisq([(4,18),(6,16),(5,-1),(-5,9)]
trisq([(4,-8),(1,7),(15,9)])

# this works as expected
plt.show()

trisq([(4,8),(12,3),(0,0),(1,9)])
# but this one returns a blank plot
plt.show()
```

---

Update:
My concrete question is: how do I show a graph, then add more elements to it and show it again in the above context and possibly repeat inside a loop? Apparently, plt.show() can only be called once and not in an ongoing manner.

Answer (score 0):

Plt.show() shows the active figures. After your first call to plt.show() there is no active figure any more.

Unfortunately the question is not clear about what the actual goal is.

You may call plt.show only once at the end.  You may also create a new figure in between.

Make sure to add the collection inside the trisq function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ImportanceOfBeingErnest! I moved the collection into the function (just missed it in copying). My goal is to have a loop and in each iteration of the loop call my trisq function once and show the result right there plus a short pause, so that I can see the growth of my arrangement of triangles and squares cells, rather than doing all the work and then showing it at once. As you pointed out, when plt.show() is called, the image gets reset.

Comment: For that consider using an animation.